# Which android context should i use in singletons?

Tags: java, android, singleton

When i write my singletons i always provide a `getInstance(Context)` method in the singleton Class. But which context object should i pass to that method: **Activity context** (the `this` in the Activity class) or the **Application Context**? And what differences it would make if i pass one or another?

To illustrate, i have a database manager that have the getInstance method defined like:

```
public static Database getInstance(Context context) {
    if (Database.instance == null)
        instance = new Database(context);
    return instance;
}
```

And the constructor looks like:

```
private Database(Context context) { 
    this.sqLiteDatabase = context.openOrCreateDatabase(...);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you pass in does not matter much. What you *use* should be the `Application` context:

```
public static Database getInstance(Context context) {
    if (Database.instance == null)
        instance = new Database(context.getApplicationContext());
    return instance;
}
```

Now, if you want to force the caller to supply the `Application`, you could do that:

```
public static Database getInstance(Application context) {
    if (Database.instance == null)
        instance = new Database(context);
    return instance;
}
```

Personally, I like to consider that an implementation detail, hidden by the API.

The `Application` is a global object, created when the process is created. Therefore it is "pre-leaked", in effect. You cannot leak it further. Other types of `Context` (e.g., `Activity`), referenced from some singleton, may result in memory leaks.

See [Dave Smith's epic blog post on the roles of different `Context` objects](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) for more.

Comment: Using the `context.getApplicationContext()` is a very nice solution to use the ApplicationContext. But i need to know what differences it makes in the app.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, could you take a minute to look at my question, I'll be really appreciated. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48161708/1602807