# Use interface to provide Android context for singleton?

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-context

I've been looking through the forks of a popular library that keep an `ApplicationContext` as a member field within a singleton. This make the app memory intensive as the process is a bit expensive. Some forks claim to solve the problem by using an anonymous class implement an interface to provide the `Context` for the singleton in demand ([here](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/blob/46616dd60f41a0f899a1508100984f8dea240f8f/android-ffmpeg/src/main/java/nl/bravobit/ffmpeg/FFmpeg.java#L33) and [here](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/blob/46616dd60f41a0f899a1508100984f8dea240f8f/android-ffmpeg/src/main/java/nl/bravobit/ffmpeg/FFmpeg.java#L33)). In general, the code can be summarized like this:

The interface:

```
public interface FFbinaryContextProvider {
    Context provide();
}
```

The singleton:

```
public class FFmpeg implements FFbinaryInterface {    
    private final FFbinaryContextProvider context;    
    private static FFmpeg instance = null;

    private FFmpeg(FFbinaryContextProvider context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static FFmpeg getInstance(final Context context) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new FFmpeg(new FFbinaryContextProvider() {
                public Context provide() {
                    return context;
                }
            });
        }

        return instance;
    }

    //get the context like this this.context.provide()
    }
}
```

An then invoke the singleton within the `Acitivity` like this `FFmpeg.getInstance(this);`

I'm not familiar with this approach.  Is it just by hiding the `Context` under an interface like this would allow the garbage collector to collect it whenever the activity get killed? Is there any resource that I can read more on this matter?

And while we are at it, if the aim is to prevent memory leaks, doesn't `WeakReference` already solve this issue? Is there any downside with using a `WeakReference` within a singleton?

Comment: As I know this technique is dependency injection. Refer to this link and google search for more detail https://tech.just-eat.com/2015/10/26/dependency-injection-on-android/

Comment: This quoted article doesn't seem to explain much about my concern.